# How to simulate the click on Refresh link in Gmail?

Tags: javascript, gmail, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script that works with Gmail. the script is working good but I need to add simulate a refresh of the Gmail page by "hitting" programmatically the Refresh button.
is this possible ? 
FYI, the refresh link in Gmail isn't a link like  but rather : Refresh
I've tried to use the click() method but it doesn't work ...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: doesn't gmail update itself from time to time?

Comment: gmail updates the threadlist every 2 minutes and I don't want to let users wait all this time to see the modifications made by the GM script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [integrate jQuery into Greasemonkey](http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/), you could easily use the `.trigger('click')` method, for a true [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent)/[fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423%28VS.85%29.aspx) work-around.

Alternatively, couldn't you just set the window.location.href to http://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox?

Comment: I'm already using jQuery in my script. I've tried trigger('click') but it doesn't work.
I'm trying the other method (using dispatchEvent) and I'm stuck with another problem : how to transform a jQuery object to a javascript object ? 'cause I'm using jQuery to select the div (AP class) and I need to "attach" it to myDiv.dispatchEvent(evt).

Comment: you can get a DOM element from a jQuery object like this: $('.selector')[0] - where 0 is the index of the element in the jQuery collection

Comment: The link about integrating jQuery into GM scripts describes an unsecure procedure that relies heavily on `unsafeWindow`. I recommend *not* following that advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423%28VS.85%29.aspx) in IE or [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) for everything else.